# creating a peer to peer game using flash and php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, web, p2p

If i want to create a website containing a game like billiards designed using actionscript 3.0, can i achieve this using php, mySQL, and AJAX? I need it to have real time updates e.g: when one player shoots the ball the other player sees it moving as well as chatting capabilities etc. Im not asking HOW to do it obviously, im only asking what language i should design the website in given that i have a flash game and want to launch it as p2p.

I have very little knowledge of building web applications and i would just like to know if i am on the right track.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is a big ask if you have no knowledge of web development, maybe start off with something smaller. Like Hello World.

Answer (score 0):

> can i achieve this using php, mySQL, and AJAX?

Yes, you can.

Look at this article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/09/building-real-time-commenting-system/

But I would use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) with [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for realtime communication.